# Where to put admin portion of web application

Tags: web-application

So this is more of a theoretical question (isn't most things in information security though??), but one that I'm kind of stuck on.

When making web application admin portals (for administration of the application, CMS stuff, etc...) how should you allow users to access it securely? I know if you're really concerned about security you should probably do it on an intranet local to your company, or at the very least whitelist ip addresses, but I can't do that because my users need to access the admin portal from anywhere in the US.

I don't know why, but admin.mywebapp.com or mywebapp.com/admin/ seems like a big security hole to me (even thought that's how Wordpress does it and security by obscurity is definitely a less important layer than the other layers), but I don't know what the right answer is here. Should it be something like mywebapp.com/admin or should it be hosted at a different url altogether (for instance mywebappadmin.com), or does it even really matter?

**How should you call the admin portion of your web app?**

Comment: There are applications like Dirbuster which attempt to enumerate directories on a website which are used in manual and automated attacks. Choosing a default folder name other than "admin" would help prevent that risk. If you allow users to specify the folder or subdomain for the admin panel that would also help in case an exploit was found it would be difficult to find the admin pannel on all instances of your app.